# cx_Oracle python delete statements in multiprocess environment

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, deadlock, sql-delete, cx-oracle

I am using python cx_Oracle and multiprocessing. I am spinning 8 processes to delete data from chain of tables. Delete statements in all 8 processes are same. But the data they are deleting is mutually exclusive.
Each process creates its own db connection runs and commits the delete statements.
With this setup currently I am getting below error

```
ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
```

Is there any way to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without providing additional information about the code you are using to perform the deletes and the table definition I can only provide general advice:

- look at the indexes set up on the table; if you are deleting rows without the use of an index you are going to be requiring a lock on the entire table instead of just on the rows being deleted
- look at the foreign keys referencing the table; by deleting these rows locks may be acquired on the child tables as well; if there are no indexes on those columns you may be locking the entire table
- examine the dba_lock table to see what locks are in fact being held
- examine your code; a deadlock can only occur if process A has acquired some locks, process B has acquired some other locks and then wants the locks acquired by process A and process A then wants to acquire the locks held by process B; it doesn't have to be only two processes as well; an entire chain of locks held by multiple processes can be the culprit